# Increment all rows with +1 where row is larger than

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have these fields

```
+------------+-------------+----------------+----------+-------------+
| channel_id | channel_row | content_digest | seriesid | provider_id |
+------------+-------------+----------------+----------+-------------+
|        296 |           0 | SVT::2258207   | NULL     | NULL        |
|        296 |           1 | SVT::2354966   | NULL     | NULL        |
|        296 |           2 | SVT::2287450   | NULL     | NULL        |
|        296 |           3 | SVT::2269811   | NULL     | NULL        |
+------------+-------------+----------------+----------+-------------+
```

And what I want to do is to increment, say all `channel_row` with `+1`, where `channel_row is <= 1`, which means 1 and 2 and 3 should become 2 and 3 and 4, and 0 should stay intact...

But this doesn't work, at least not in 1 sql-query which i now have :

```
UPDATE channel_row SET channel_row = channel_row+1 WHERE channel_id = '296' AND channel_row <= '1' ORDER BY channel_row DESC
```

But there must be some way, right? Or is this actually not possible?

Comment: shouldn't it be >= 1?

Answer (score 2):

Your where statement is wrong:

```
AND channel_row <= '1'
```

must be

```
AND channel_row >= '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong condition, `<=` it should be `>=`

```
UPDATE channel_row 
SET channel_row = channel_row+1 
WHERE channel_id = '296' 
AND channel_row >= '1' ORDER BY channel_row DESC
```

Here is a simple test case

```
mysql> create table test (id int , val int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.16 sec)

mysql> insert into test values (1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(1,3);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from test ;
+------+------+
| id   | val  |
+------+------+
|    1 |    0 |
|    1 |    1 |
|    1 |    2 |
|    1 |    3 |
+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> update test set val=val+1 where id = 1 and val > 0 ;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from test ;
+------+------+
| id   | val  |
+------+------+
|    1 |    0 |
|    1 |    2 |
|    1 |    3 |
|    1 |    4 |
+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `<=` is not correct. You want to update all higher `0` so it have to be `channel_row > 0`. Also the number should not be in `''`

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET channel_row = channel_row + 1 
WHERE channel_id = 296 AND channel_row > 0
```

The `ORDER BY` statement is not needed

Comment: Seems that i need "ORDER BY", because without it, i get "Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '296-3' for key 'PRIMARY'", and if i use ORDER BY, i don't get it.

Comment: Okay, I edit the solution. You have to put the table name after `UPDATE`. Maybe then you do not need the `ORDER BY` statement